# GLEW from apt-get have no include files

Tags: apt, dpkg

enviroment info:ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I just `sudo apt-get install glew-utils`. But when I `find / -name "*glew*"` I got someting like this:

```
/usr/share/doc/libglewmx1.10
/usr/share/doc/glew-utils
/usr/share/doc/libglew1.10
/usr/bin/glewinfo
```

But the expected `/include` and `/lib` is missed!

The apt-get have some error with something I don't know, which is called cups here. And dpkg seams to be blocked by this cups. Is my assumption right? And how to fix it?

```
ndn-07@ndn07-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install glew-utils 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
glew-utils is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1293 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up cups-daemon (2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2) ...
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd at line 145: syntax error, unexpected TOK_CONDLISTID, expecting TOK_MODE
update-rc.d: warning: default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match cups Default-Stop values (1)
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 1: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /sbin/runlevel: not found
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript cups, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package cups-daemon (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-core-drivers:
 cups-core-drivers depends on cups-daemon (>= 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-core-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups:
 cups depends on cups-core-drivers (>= 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package cups-core-drivers is not configured yet.
 cups depends on cups-daemon (>= 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

====================

something error when update & upgrade might have relation to this problem:

====================  update

```
Hit http://mirrors.163.com vivid-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://mirrors.163.com vivid-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://mirrors.163.com vivid-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://mirrors.163.com vivid-backports/universe Translation-en
Fetched 7,962 kB in 2min 46s (47.8 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/mirrors.163.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_main_i18n_Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/mirrors.163.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/mirrors.163.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

================= upgrade

```
 xul-ext-ubufox xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts
  xul-ext-websites-integration yelp yelp-xsl zeitgeist zeitgeist-core
  zeitgeist-datahub zenity zenity-common zlib1g
963 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 330 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 331 kB/363 MB of archives.
After this operation, 94.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main libasound2 amd64 1.0.28-1 [331 kB]
Fetched 374 kB in 0s (1,715 kB/s)  
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2_1.0.28-1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

=============== apt-get install -f

```
 xserver-common xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-video-all xterm
  xul-ext-ubufox xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts
  xul-ext-websites-integration yelp yelp-xsl zeitgeist zeitgeist-core
  zeitgeist-datahub zenity zenity-common zlib1g
963 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 330 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 331 kB/363 MB of archives.
After this operation, 94.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main libasound2 amd64 1.0.28-1 [331 kB]
Fetched 374 kB in 0s (1,715 kB/s)  
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2_1.0.28-1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
ndn-07@ndn07-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1293 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up cups-daemon (2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2) ...
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd at line 145: syntax error, unexpected TOK_CONDLISTID, expecting TOK_MODE
update-rc.d: warning: default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match cups Default-Stop values (1)
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 1: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /sbin/runlevel: not found
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript cups, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package cups-daemon (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-core-drivers:
 cups-core-drivers depends on cups-daemon (>= 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-core-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups:
 cups depends on cups-core-drivers (>= 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package cups-core-drivers is not configured yet.
 cups depends on cups-daemon (>= 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 cups-daemon
 cups-core-drivers
 cups
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

============== after clean apt list

```
  xul-ext-ubufox xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts
  xul-ext-websites-integration yelp yelp-xsl zeitgeist zeitgeist-core
  zeitgeist-datahub zenity zenity-common zlib1g
963 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 330 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 331 kB/363 MB of archives.
After this operation, 94.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main libasound2 amd64 1.0.28-1 [331 kB]
Fetched 374 kB in 0s (973 kB/s)    
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2_1.0.28-1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
ndn-07@ndn07-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1293 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up cups-daemon (2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2) ...
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd at line 145: syntax error, unexpected TOK_CONDLISTID, expecting TOK_MODE
update-rc.d: warning: default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match cups Default-Stop values (1)
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 1: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /sbin/runlevel: not found
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript cups, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package cups-daemon (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-core-drivers:
 cups-core-drivers depends on cups-daemon (>= 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-core-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups:
 cups depends on cups-core-drivers (>= 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package cups-core-drivers is not configured yet.
 cups depends on cups-daemon (>= 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                     E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ndn-07@ndn07-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install glew-utils
```

Comment: Kindly post the full error message not just 'The apt-get have some error with something I don't know'

Comment: @Parto sorry, I have edited it again.

Comment: What is your ubuntu version?

Comment: @Parto 14.04LTS, do you need any other info? :)

Comment: I will request as I go along. For now try `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade` then `sudo apt-get install -f` in that order. Edit your question then include the output where an error shows up.

Comment: @Parto I would.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38079/discussion-between-parto-and-frank-wang).

Comment: Okay, we need to clean up your lists first. Run this `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` then `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` as above.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this? If not, tell me so that I can start a bounty for you.

Comment: @Parto Not, yet. It's very surprising to hear you again.

Comment: Have started a bounty for you...no worries. I'm sure someone will come along and help you solve this.

Comment: Hello. Have you solved your 'dpkg error' issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're expecting it to install anything into those directories. But what you're seeing is correct, there is nothing wrong with the package.

The package provides the following files:

```
/usr/bin/glewinfo  
/usr/bin/visualinfo  
/usr/share/doc/glew-utils/README.txt  
/usr/share/doc/glew-utils/TODO.txt  
/usr/share/doc/glew-utils/changelog.Debian.gz  
/usr/share/doc/glew-utils/copyright
```

Source: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/glew-utils/filelist

Comment: @FrankWang Have you solved your 'dpkg error' issue?

Comment: @Parto No, but 'dpkg error' issue seams have no affect on my using. As the answer said, the package ubuntu provides has not included the lib and include files at all. It's quite drama, and I felt guilty about your offering of the bounty. After all, I installed it through source code and it works.

Comment: It's cool. That's why we are here, to help each other. Am happy for the opportunity.